# Вывести строки принадлежащие пользователю

Tags: sql, база-данных, asp.net

Вывожу данные из бд с помощью GridView.

```
SelectCommand=
"SELECT
    Products.Image,
    Products.Name,
    Products.Description,
    Products.Price,
    Cart.Amount,
    Cart.ClientId
FROM
  (Cart INNER JOIN Products ON Cart.ProductId = Products.id)";
```

Нужно теперь вывести только те записи, где

```
//ключ текущего юзера, именно так я и записывал в таблицу Cart
Cart.ClientId = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString();
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос если честно. Не пробывали использовать в запросе WHERE ?

Comment: При регистрации пользователю системой присваивается ключ(айдишкник). Пользователь добавляя в корзину товар, передаёт в в таблицу корзины свой айдишник. На странице корзины нужно вывести только товар добавленный пользователем.

Answer (score 1):

Вам скорее всего нужно что то такое:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("ClientId", Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString());
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "
    SELECT Products.Image,
       Products.Name,
       Products.Description,
       Products.Price,
       Cart.Amount,
       Cart.ClientId
    FROM (Cart
    INNER JOIN Products ON Cart.ProductId = Products.id
    WHERE Cart.ClientId = @ClientId";
```

Или

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ...
SelectCommand = "SELECT Products.Image,
       Products.Name,
       Products.Description,
       Products.Price,
       Cart.Amount,
       Cart.ClientId
    FROM (Cart
    INNER JOIN Products ON Cart.ProductId = Products.id
    WHERE Cart.ClientId = @ClientId">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:DelegateParameter Name="ClientId"...
</SelectParameters>
```

С другими примерами можно познакомится [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/485821/2546083)