# Как в sql запрос передать значение MembershipUser.ProviderUserKey

Tags: sql, база-данных, .net

Запрос:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT Products.Image,Products.Name,Products.Description,Products.Price,Cart.Amount,Cart.ClientId FROM (Cart INNER JOIN Products ON Cart.ProductId = Products.id) WHERE Cart.ClientId = UserId">
```

Как в `UserId` передать `MembershipUser.ProviderUserKey`?

Comment: Откуда передать?

Comment: MembershipUser.ProviderUserKey это ключ пользователя под которым я зашёл

Comment: Представьте, пожалуйста, что Вы ничего не знаете о задаче, над которой работает какой-то программист. И вот этот программист Вас зовет и просит помочь. Теперь прочитайте Ваш вопрос. Ну и как?

Comment: При регистрации пользователю системой присваивается ключ(UserId , получить его можно с помощью Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString()). Пользователь добавляя в корзину товар, передаёт в таблицу корзины свой айдишник. На странице корзины нужно вывести только товар добавленный пользователем( где UserId = MembershipUser.ProviderUserKey)

Comment: Где находится этот атрибут SelectCommand? Свойством какого объекта (какого типа) он является? Позволяет ли этот SqlDataAdapter задать команды с параметрами? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Это элемент SqlDataSource

Comment: Alas, I give up.

Comment: Попытался прописать так:--------------
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
         SelectCommand="SELECT Products.Image,Products.Name,Products.Description,Products.Price,Cart.Amount,Cart.ClientId FROM (Cart INNER JOIN Products ON Cart.ProductId = Products.id) WHERE (Cart.ClientId = @UserID)">
    <SelectParameters>
           <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.String()" Name="UserID"
                Type="Object" /> 
    </SelectParameters>
-------------
Но ничего не выводит

Comment: Я уже отвечал [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/469405/2110) Используйте параметры.